# sqlite3 python - постоянно выводит значение 1

Tags: python, telebot, sqlite3

Мне нужно вывести из базы данных (sqlite3) значение в столбце `welcome_msg_status`, когда я его вывожу - мне постоянно пишет, что оно равно 1. Менял значения на другие и вообще удалял - значение все равно 1. В чем может быть проблема?

```
def dbtest(message):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('dba.db', check_same_thread=False)
    cur = conn.cursor()

    group_id = message.chat.id

    cur.execute('SELECT EXISTS(SELECT welcome_msg_status FROM groups WHERE groupid = ("%s"))' % group_id)
    status = cur.fetchall()

    for elem in status:
        print(elem[0])
        if elem[0] == 0:
            bot.reply_to(message, text="Приветствую тебя, это дефолтное сообщения приветствия! -- 0")
        elif elem[0] == 1:
            bot.reply_to(message, text="Приветствую тебя, это настроенное сообщение приветствия! -- 1")
        else:
            bot.reply_to(message, text="Ошибка")
```

Comment: а зачем там EXISTS?

Comment: вообще идет как проверка на наличие данных с определенным айди, но я так понимаю, что использую её неправильно. Прошу прощение если это так, только изучаю это и практикуюсь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как я понимаю, `EXIST` в вашем коде действительно проверяет, есть ли такая строчка, но возвращает булевые значения в числах: `1` (**True**) или `0` (**False**). Рекомендую вам такой метод проверки:

```
cur.execute('SELECT welcome_msg_status FROM groups WHERE groupid = ("%s"))' % group_id)
if cur.fetchone()==None:#Если не существует
    ...
else:#Если существует
    ...
```

---

*P.S. Проверил на своей БД, действительно строчка `cur.execute('SELECT EXISTS(SELECT welcome_msg_status FROM groups WHERE groupid = ("%s"))' % group_id)` выводит "булевые числовые" значения*

Comment: смотрите, когда создаются данные о группе - welcome_msg_status по умолчанию указывается как 0(что я сделал сам), сделал это для определенния какой тип приветствия стоит в беседе(если 0 - дефолтное, если 1 - пользовательское). Если я правильно понимаю, то в вашем случае он проверяет только наличие данных в столбце

Comment: а нет, неправильно понял код, который вы написали, тогда попробую его и отпишусь

Comment: если существует, просто используйте его

Comment: Если помог - поставьте галочку)